Is there any way to simulate touch events on iOS devices such as iPad?
I have coded it so that when you run this, it prompts for cps, and generates a red dot as indicator where you click, I don’t believe that this is working for ios, is there any way to make this work? This is intended to be ran as a bookmark.
let cps = parseInt(prompt("Enter clicks per second (CPS):"), 10);
if (isNaN(cps) || cps <= 0) {
    cps = 1; // Default to 1 CPS if invalid input
}

function createRedDot(x, y) {
    const redDot = document.createElement('div');
    redDot.style.position = 'absolute';
    redDot.style.width = '10px';
    redDot.style.height = '10px';
    redDot.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    redDot.style.borderRadius = '50%';
    redDot.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    redDot.style.left = `${x - 5}px`;
    redDot.style.top = `${y - 5}px`;
    document.body.appendChild(redDot);
   
    setTimeout(() => {
        redDot.remove();
    }, 1000);
}
function simulateTouch(x, y) {
    const targetElement = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);

    if (targetElement) {
        const touchStartEvent = new Event('touchstart', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true });
        touchStartEvent.touches = [{ clientX: x, clientY: y, target: targetElement }];
        targetElement.dispatchEvent(touchStartEvent);
        const touchEndEvent = new Event('touchend', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true });
        touchEndEvent.changedTouches = [{ clientX: x, clientY: y, target: targetElement }];
        targetElement.dispatchEvent(touchEndEvent);
    }
}
let isAutoClicking = false;
function startAutoClicking(x, y) {
    if (isAutoClicking) return; 
    isAutoClicking = true;
    const interval = 1000 / cps; // Calculate interval based on CPS
    const clickInterval = setInterval(() => {
        simulateTouch(x, y);
    }, interval);

    // Stop clicking after 5 seconds to prevent continuous clicking
    setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(clickInterval);
        isAutoClicking = false;
    }, 5000);
}
document.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
    const touch = e.touches[0];
    const x = touch.clientX;
    const y = touch.clientY;
    createRedDot(x, y);
    startAutoClicking(x, y);
});



I tried changing the any the auto clicker works, and limited the rate of clicking, everything works except to the clicking part, as I’m not quite familiar with iOS systems and how they click.
This is the bookmarklet version.

javascript:(function()%7Blet%20cps=parseInt(prompt(%22Enter%20clicks%20per%20second%20(CPS)%3A%22),10);if(isNaN(cps)%7C%7Ccps%3C=0)%7Bcps=1;%7Dfunction%20createRedDot(x,y)%7Bconst%20redDot=document.createElement('div');redDot.style.position='absolute';redDot.style.width='10px';redDot.style.height='10px';redDot.style.backgroundColor='red';redDot.style.borderRadius='50%25';redDot.style.pointerEvents='none';redDot.style.left=%60$%7Bx-5%7Dpx%60;redDot.style.top=%60$%7By-5%7Dpx%60;document.body.appendChild(redDot);setTimeout(()=%3E%7BredDot.remove();%7D,1000);%7Dfunction%20simulateTouch(x,y)%7Bconst%20targetElement=document.elementFromPoint(x,y);if(targetElement)%7Bconst%20touchStartEvent=new%20Event('touchstart',%7Bbubbles%3Atrue,cancelable%3Atrue%7D);touchStartEvent.touches=%5B%7BclientX%3Ax,clientY%3Ay,target%3AtargetElement%7D%5D;targetElement.dispatchEvent(touchStartEvent);const%20touchEndEvent=new%20Event('touchend',%7Bbubbles%3Atrue,cancelable%3Atrue%7D);touchEndEvent.changedTouches=%5B%7BclientX%3Ax,clientY%3Ay,target%3AtargetElement%7D%5D;targetElement.dispatchEvent(touchEndEvent);%7D%7Dlet%20isAutoClicking=false;function%20startAutoClicking(x,y)%7Bif(isAutoClicking)return;isAutoClicking=true;const%20interval=1000/cps;const%20clickInterval=setInterval(()=%3E%7BsimulateTouch(x,y);%7D,interval);setTimeout(()=%3E%7BclearInterval(clickInterval);isAutoClicking=false;%7D,5000);%7Ddocument.addEventListener('touchstart',(e)=%3E%7Bconst%20touch=e.touches%5B0%5D;const%20x=touch.clientX;const%20y=touch.clientY;createRedDot(x,y);startAutoClicking(x,y);%7D);%7D)();%0A



the code is not formatted. Please can you do so?

Sorry, I formatted it.
